# Return results from a call to Yield Return

Tags: c#, performance, lazy-evaluation, yield-return

I often find the scenario where I return an IEnumerable using the `yield return` statement, then have other methods which call this function with different parameters and directly return the result.

Is there any performance benefit to iterating through the results end `yield return`ing these as opposed to simply returning the collection?  i.e. if I use `return` on the resulting IEnumberable rather than looping through these results again and using `yield return` does the compiler know to only generate the results as they're required, or does it wait for the entire collection to be returned before returning all results?

```
public class Demo
{
    private IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers(int x)
    {
        //imagine this operation were more expensive than this demo version
        //e.g. calling a web service on each iteration.
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }
    //does this wait for the full list before returning
    public IEnumerable<int> GetNumbersWrapped()
    {
        return GetNumbers(10);
    }
    //whilst this allows the benefits of Yield Return to persist?
    public IEnumerable<int> GetNumbersWrappedYield()
    {
        foreach (int i in GetNumbers(10))
            yield return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably you have tested this by putting breakpoints at strategic points, or adding some delays like a Thread.Sleep before your yield calls. What have those tests told you?

Comment: Just a guess, but since `GetNumbers` returns `IEnumerable` yield will probably "bubble up".

Comment: @BrianO''Byrne: I admit I headed straight here rather than testing for myself - my justification was that I wanted to know the Why as well as the What, and also suspected others may have the same question / would want to be able to look up the answer without all having to rewrite the same test code.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was downvoted. It helped me understand and solve the problem of combining yield return and using clause with an IDisposable-implementing class. This is where the difference between GetNumbersWrapped() and GetNumbersWrappedYield() matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetNumbersWrapped` simply passes through the original enumerable - it hasn't even invoked the iterator at that point. The end result remains fully deferred / lazy / spooling / whatever else.

`GetNumbersWrappedYield` adds an *extra* layer of abstraction - so now, every call to `MoveNext` has to do *ever so slightly* more work; not enough to cause pain. It too will be fully deferred / lazy / spooling / whatever else - but adds some minor overheads. Usually these minor overheads are justified by the fact that you are adding some value such as filtering or additional processing; but not really in this example.

Note: one thing that `GetNumbersWrappedYield` *does* do is prevent abuse by callers. For example, if `GetNumbers` was:

```
private IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers(int x)
{
    return myPrivateSecretList;
}
```

then callers of `GetNumbersWrapped` can *abuse* this:

```
IList list = (IList)GetNumbers(4);
list.Clear();
list.Add(123); // mwahahaahahahah
```

However, callers of `GetNumbersWrappedYield` **cannot** do this... at least, not quite as easily. They could, of course, still use reflection to pull the iterator apart, obtain the wrapped inner reference, and cast *that*.

This, however, is not usually a genuine concern.

Answer (score 2):

A function that returns an `IEnumerable<T>` is indeed returning an object, which is not the full list but knows how to iterate it when its `Enumerator`'s `MoveNext` method is called. The same is true for your `GetNumbersWrapped` method above. It doesn't wait for the full collection. It returns an object which has an `Enumerator` inside. Whenever the `foreach` loop (or other loop operations) call this enumerator's `MoveNext` method it starts reading the values. So `GetNumbersWrapped` and `GetNumbersWrappedYield` are the same, except that `GetNumbersWrappedYield` has one redundant looping layer.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your question, the function `GetNumbersWrapped` does not wait for the full list before returning because it's return type is an IEnumerable and the execution of the inner loop inside `GetNumbers` is deferred.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, `IEnumerable<T>` is evaluated lazily. This means that all three methods will effectively do exactly the same, but the `GetNumbersWrappedYield` will just be wrapped in a redundant enumerator. There won't be any performance benefit by doing this, in fact, the extra enumerator will introduce a slight overhead. I'd stick with the `GetNumbers` directly.